# jQuery form submission error

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="user_submit.php" id="addUserForm">
        <p>
            <label for="username">Enter Username:*</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </p>
         <p>
            <label for="firstname">Enter First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
        </p>
```

:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="addUser" value="1" />
        <p><input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit_AddUser" onClick="validate_addUser();" ></p>
```

this is the simple js im using

```
function validate_addUser(){
    if (!$('#username').val())
        alert('Please enter Username');
    else if (!$('#firstname').val())
        alert("Please enter first name");
    else if (!$('#lastname').val())
        alert("Please enter last name");
    else if (!$('#email').val())
        alert("Please enter email address");
    else 
        $('#addUserForm').submit();

}
```

When I submit the form, this is the error that im getting

```
e[h] is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...{href:function(a){return a.getAttribute("href")
```

Comment: Your code seems okay, perhaps you should retry with jQuery development version; that should give you more details

Comment: how is form submitting? if you don't have a submit handler, validation function won't stop it submitting regardless if it validates or not

Comment: @charlietfl You can just call `submit()` on a form with no problem, it's even an example in the [jQuery `.submit` docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: @DaveNewton  I realize you can call submit, but without returning false in clcik handler there is nothing stopping default submit if validation test fails

Comment: @DaveNewton, charlietfl is right, without preventing default behavior  you can't check the form.

Comment: @charlietfl Correct, but that's a different issue--it's not a handler that's necessary, it's stopping default processing on a validation error. And while important, it's not what's causing the error, I think.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I agree, and nothing shown would cause href attribute error in core either, so my original point was to see any submit handling code

Comment: @charlietfl, I think it's not a input `type=submit`, so by default it won't be submitted.

Comment: @SheikhHeera It's a form, which you can call `submit()` on.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I know, I meant that there is no need to prevent default because by default an input `type=button` doesn't submit a form.

Comment: @Dave
I'll definitely try to improve my aceept rate but most of my questions remains unanswered, thats why.

Comment: @Indy Fair enough--can't accept answers that aren't there ;)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the name from submit to go and it started working, dyaamn!!

```
<input type="button" name="go" value="go" id="gogogo" onClick="validate_addUser();" >
```

Comment: Weird, but taking the name "submit" out worked for me as well.